# Does Google Identity Platform support encrypted SAML assertion?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

We're using Google Identity Platform (Firebase Authentication ft. Google Identity Toolkit) as IDaaS, mainly for SAML 2.0.

When an IdP returns an encrypted SAML response assertion, Identity Toolkit throws the following error: `INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE has no assertions`, but if assertions are not encrypted, everything seems to work fine.

So does Google Identity Platform supports encrypted assertions in SAMLresponse? Couldn't find anything in the documentation about whether it's supported or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Identity Platform does not support encrypted assertions in SAML responses. You can confirm this from the REST API for [configuration SAML providers](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.inboundSamlConfigs#InboundSamlConfig). Notice they don't provide a public key for IdP encryption (normally for encrypted SAML, the SP would generate an asymmetric key pair, they would keep the private key and you would configure the public key for encryption with your IdP).

Comment: Thanks @bojeil! 

I thought the public `SpCertificate` could be used by the IdP to encrypt the assertion as well and that GIP would use the private key to decrypt it, but looks like I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Henoc what was your workaround? I'm also using Firebase to handle identity on my platform, but one client's IdP sends us encrypted SAML responses.

Comment: @PranavPillai unfortunately it is not possible to receive encrypted SAML responses at the moment. You need to ask the IdP to return responses unencrypted. They should have request you a metadata xml file; make sure you are not indicating in that file that response should come encrypted.

Comment: As of January 2024, integrating Firebase with a Shibboleth IdP for SAML appears impossible. Shibboleth, widely used by universities, encrypts attributes by default, and most institutions are unable or unwilling to disable this. While Firebase allows for request signing and SPI certificate acquisition via its API [1], it doesn't support attribute decryption. Consequently, Shibboleth cannot import an XML without an encryption certificate, and Firebase's lack of decryption capabilities leads to integration failure.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#signing_requests